# I cant import the ucf 101 dataset (torchvision), 'list index out of range' error

Tags: python, dataset, pytorch, torchvision

```
dataset = torchvision.datasets.UCF101(r'my_directory', annotation_path=r'my_directory2', frames_per_clip=16, step_between_clips=1, frame_rate=None, fold=1, train=True, transform=transforms.Compose([transforms.ToTensor()]), _precomputed_metadata=None, num_workers=1, _video_width=64, _video_height=64, _video_min_dimension=0, _audio_samples=0)
```

This line works, the problem is when I try to do any kind of operation using 'dataset', in particular this one:

```
data = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=512, shuffle=True)
```

I get the error, so i can't work on the video data because I can't use the dataLoader, the error is:

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Complete error message:

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-dc3631481cb3> in <module>
----> 1 data = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=512, shuffle=True)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\dataloader.py in __init__(self, dataset, batch_size, shuffle, sampler, batch_sampler, num_workers, collate_fn, pin_memory, drop_last, timeout, worker_init_fn, multiprocessing_context)
    211             else:  # map-style
    212                 if shuffle:
--> 213                     sampler = RandomSampler(dataset)
    214                 else:
    215                     sampler = SequentialSampler(dataset)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\sampler.py in __init__(self, data_source, replacement, num_samples)
     90                              "since a random permute will be performed.")
     91 
---> 92         if not isinstance(self.num_samples, int) or self.num_samples <= 0:
     93             raise ValueError("num_samples should be a positive integer "
     94                              "value, but got num_samples={}".format(self.num_samples))

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\sampler.py in num_samples(self)
     98         # dataset size might change at runtime
     99         if self._num_samples is None:
--> 100             return len(self.data_source)
    101         return self._num_samples
    102 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torchvision\datasets\ucf101.py in __len__(self)
     96 
     97     def __len__(self):
---> 98         return self.video_clips.num_clips()
     99 
    100     def __getitem__(self, idx):

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torchvision\datasets\video_utils.py in num_clips(self)
    241         Number of subclips that are available in the video list.
    242         """
--> 243         return self.cumulative_sizes[-1]
    244 
    245     def get_clip_location(self, idx):

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem:

This problem occurs when you run your code on windows because windows paths use backslash ("\") instead of forward slash ("/").

As you see in the code:

https://github.com/pytorch/vision/blob/7b9d30eb7c4d92490d9ac038a140398e0a690db6/torchvision/datasets/ucf101.py#L94

So, this line of code reads the file path from label file as “action\video_name” and merge it with “root” path using backslash therefore full path becomes like “root\action/video_name”. Such paths doesn’t match with the video lists at line#97 and returns empty list for indices variable.

Solution:

Two of possible solutions can be:

1. Replace the forwardslashes “/” in the label files with backslashes “\”.
2. Override the _select_fold(…) function of class UCF101 and fix the backslashes inside the function